# How do I define a variable to all php pages?

Tags: php

I have `generate.php` & `show.php`, in `show.php` i use to define `$db` to use `$result = $db->Show_keys();`

`show.php` content:

```
// Connect to the database server and select database.

    $db = createDatabaseConnection($db_type, $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $table_prefix);


    if (!$db instanceof KEYDatabase) {
        die(get_lang('no_db_connection'));
    }

    $result = $db->Show_keys();

        foreach ( $result as $row )
        {
            echo $row['key_value']."<br>";
        }
```

in `generate.php` i need also to define `$db` to use `$db->addkey($key_value,$key_balance,$key_created_date)` !

`generate.php` content:

```
// Connect to the database server and select database.
$db = createDatabaseConnection($db_type, $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $table_prefix);


if (!$db instanceof KEYDatabase) {
    die(get_lang('no_db_connection'));
}

$key_value = serialkey();

$key_balance = 10;

$key_created_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");


if ($db->addkey($key_value,$key_balance,$key_created_date))

{
    echo 'New Key add to database!<br>'.$key_value;
}
```

So now my friends, how do i define `$db = createDatabaseConnection($db_type, $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $table_prefix);`
for one time?

Comment: Your whole premise is wrong. You should not have made a DB class. Instead you should have used either PDO or MySQLi instance and passed that instance to all the classes that need to use it. What you have no is a procedural mess.

Comment: @tereško As much as I appreciate your view, I beg to differ, OP seems to be at a very nascent stage of learning his ropes so, maybe cutting him some slack and letting him experiment and explore would be better suited instead of throwing the complex coding standards and good practices, judging by the question itself its pretty evident he has jsut begun looking at the language, lets give him some thing working first. IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a third file with the database connection and then `include`/`requre` it anywhere you want.

**FILE:** connection.php

```
<?php
$db = createDatabaseConnection($db_type, $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $table_prefix);
```

**FILE:** generate.php

```
require_once('connection.php'); // Considering that the files are under same parent directory
```

Now you can use `$db` anywhere in the file `generate.php`

Answer (score 2):

Create a `db.php` file in which you define `$db` then call it at the beginning of your php files like that `require_once('db.php');`

Answer (score 1):

The oop way (and maybe software architecture clean way) would be to use dependency injection and ioc. That's also the way to go in every modern php framework. If you use Laravel or something similar, thats already build in. Just have a look at [php-di.org](http://php-di.org)

If you create an class with dependency injection, it's part of your di container to automatically resolve the constructor parameters and pass an suitable object.

```
class Foo
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(KEYDatabase $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

and later create the class with your container.

```
$foo = $container->get('Foo');
```